# Find the nim-sum of all numbers from $1$ to $((2^n)-1)$ where $n >1$ is a natural number

Tags: game-theory

I started learning nim sum, the examples given in class were all two number kind of problem. What should I do with this kind of problem?

Comment: Try computing small values ($n=2,3,4$, say) by hand. You will see a pattern.

Comment: Is the pattern just 2^n ? how should i express my answer ?

Comment: What is the nim-sum of $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,$ and $7$, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

So the nim-sum of any amount of numbers is determined by taking the binary representation of the numbers and where theres an odd number of 1's you take put a 1 and an even number you put a zero.  So for example with:

1001
1111
0101

Our result is 0011 because we have 2 1's in the eights digit, 2 1's in the fours digit, 1 1 in the 2's digit, and 3 1's in the ones digit.

Let us write out the binary representations for the numbers up to n=3 for the original problem.

001
010
011
100
101
110
111

Note that we have an even number of digits in each slot, so the nim-sum is 0.  This pattern continues for all n>1, where the nim-sum is 0.